# IBM bluemix dashboard error

Tags: ibm-cloud

After login into bluemix dashboard, getting below error:

> You don't have access to any organizations or spaces. Check that you have access to Cloud Foundry and at least one organization and space, and then try again. You can confirm you have the appropriate access with your account owner or administrator.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates you don’t have the correct access permissions for any organizations/spaces tied to your account.

You should be able to create a new org and space from your account page (depends on your plan), and subsequently, set the permissions.

If you think that you should have access to a particular org/space but are still getting that warning, I recommend opening up a support ticket so IBM Cloud support can have all the details related to your account to help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happen when the interface is set to the wrong region or space - click on the "person" in the top right hand corner and check that the Account is correct.  Then use the menu in the top left to choose the dashboard and along the top check that the region, org and space is set as you expect.  Hope this helps!